# How to replace/remove substring followed by a number in varchar column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a table that has a `ServiceComment` column that is a combination of the other columns in the table.

[image]

How would I remove the substring `DIST:` and the following number before the `Description:` from the `ServiceComment` column?

I can figure out how to remove the `DIST:` from the `ServiceComment` column using

```
REPLACE(ServiceComment, 'DIST:', '')
```

which returns this result:

[image]

Looking for a way to remove both the `DIST:` and the preceding number like this

[image]

Or would it be easier to add the `DIST: number` to the other records in the table somehow?

Comment: `REPLACE(ServiceComment, 'DIST: ' + DIST, '')` is an option here or generate the description again.

Comment: Zhorov's `REPLACE` soultion is great, provided that the number in the string is always formatted this simple. If it is possible to find `'DIST: 05'` or `'DIST: 1,000,000'` in the ServiceComment, then you must instead of removing the DIST part with `REPLACE`, find and combine the substrings before and after, thus leaving DIST out or follow Zhorov's other suggestion to build the string from the other columns.

Comment: On a side note: Why do you store the `ServiceComment` at all, when you can always generate it from the other columns? You shouldn't. Avoid redundancy in your database in order to avoid inconsistencies

Answer (score 0):

Try with `REPLACE(ServiceComment,'DIST: ' + Convert(varchar, DIST), '')`

Answer (score 0):

The result string you are looking for consists of two parts: The one before the DIST expression and the one after. Use `CHARINDEX` to find 'DIST: ' and then the blank following the DIST expression. Then use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to get the parts.

```
select
  left(servicecomment, charindex('DIST: ', servicecomment) - 1) +
  right(servicecomment, len(servicecomment) - charindex(' ', servicecomment, charindex('DIST: ', servicecomment) + 6))
from mytable;
```

Or look for 'Description: ' if this is guaranteed to occur only once right after 'DIST: nnn':

```
select
  left(servicecomment, charindex('DIST: ', servicecomment) - 1) +
  right(servicecomment, len(servicecomment) - charindex('Description: ', servicecomment) + 1)
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to remove the substring DIST: and the following number before the Description:

```
    SELECT REPLACE(
              coment,
              SUBSTRING(
                           coment,
                           (CHARINDEX('dist:', coment, 1)),
                           (CHARINDEX('description', coment, 1)) - (CHARINDEX('dist:', coment, 1))
                       ),
              ''
          )
```

FROM aa;

Answer (score 0):

This approach splits the string based on the semicolons and then excludes sub-strings WHERE [value] NOT LIKE ' %[0-9]% DIST'.  To make sure the sub-string capitalization matches exactly the collation is changed to CS (which is "Case Sensitive").  If you're using other collation then adjust accordingly.  Lastly, the query re-aggregates the string and re-adds the semicolons using the STRING_AGG function.  These functions where added in 2016.  Please let know if earlier version of SQL Server is being used.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(500)= 'PR: 0008 PO: 007 LINE: 3 DIST: 1 Description: This is another comment';

WITH split_cte(split_str)
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, ':')
         WHERE [value] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NOT LIKE ' %[0-9]% DIST')
     SELECT STRING_AGG(split_str, ':')
     FROM split_cte;
```